# Show default value in drop down text box when there is single value in list

Tags: html, angular

If the drop down has only one value, then I need to show that value as default value in drop down.

Eg: If "Fruits" drop down has only 1 value, then I need to show that value as default value

`<div *ngIf='items.length>0'>`

`<span *ngIf= "isAllFruitsSelected; else Fruitname">{{'ALL'}}</span>`

`<ng-template #Fruitname>`
`{{this.form.value.selectedFruits.length}} + 'Fruit Selected'}}`
`</ng-template>`
`</div>`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<ng-template #Fruitname>
{{ this.form.value.selectedFruits.length = 1 ? this.form.value.selectedFruits[0]?.name : (this.form.value.selectedFruits.length + 'Fruit Selected') }}
```

- If selectedFruits is an array of fruit names (strings), you don't need the *?.name*. (just this.form.value.selectedFruits[0]).
- If it is an object array, you should change the attribute 'name' in **?.name* for the suitable attribute for your objects.